# android studio "Activity class does not exist"

Tags: android, android-studio

After importing my eclipse android app into android studio(*Importing Non-Android-Studio project*), I've tried to run the app on my phone.

No I'm facing:

> Error type 3
>   Error: Activity class {com.abc.appname/com.abc.appname.MainActivity} does not exist.

I've searched and I've read every single article about this topic but couldn't resolve my problem.
Somehow android studio tries to find my package inside the package.

I've specified the **launch activity** in the **run configuration** by going trough the projects directory.
If I specify only the activity name as *MainActivity* it doesn't works because it request the whole package path.

The other stuff as modules and so on was autogenereted, but I couldn't find anything usefull in there.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you add the activity in your manifest.xml ?

Comment: Something strange happend.
After I've delete a strange duplicate of application tag the whole thing runs now perfectly on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem for me was solved by lowering Compiling SDK from "M preview" to API 22 in Project Structure.
But first try uninstalling app in the emulator or device you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen this when the app was already installed, but under a Work Profile. Deleting the app from the Work Profile first fixed it.